# Use module.exports function within same file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to just create a simple constant that will be available throughout my application. I don't know if this is the best way to do it.

I have

`module.exports = { GET: 'get', POST: 'post', DELETE: 'delete' }`

if i wanted to reference this inside the same js file how would i go about doing it? currently i have

`var http = module.exports = { GET: 'get' }`

now i should be able to access it within the .js file as `http.GET`
does this work? and what would be the difference between

`var http = module.exports.GET = 'get'` and `var http = module.exports = { GET: 'get' }` ? Are they exactly identical or is there some differences between the two.

Answer (score 0):

> does this work?

Yes.

But you could also drop the `http` and just refer to `module.exports.GET` every time.

> what would be the difference between `var http = module.exports.GET = 'get'`
>   and `var http = module.exports = { GET: 'get' }`?

The most obvious difference is that in one case your `http` variable contains an object and in the other a string.

Also, in the first case you are extending the existing `module.exports` object (which is initialised as an empty object, so no difference in the result) and in the second case you are overwriting the `.exports` property of the `module` with a new object. This only makes a real difference if you're doing this multiple times though.

Comment: Thanks, my buddy raised the same concerns. the reason the http exists is because i put all the HTTP methods in there. So it it has GET/POST/PUT/DELETE. i should have probably put that there. That way i could access these methods individually on import with {GET, POST} instead of bringing the whole object.